# Can't login to account after migration 1.6 to 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have migrated all my Db from a Magento 1.6.0 to Magento 2.3.3 all the products are ok and I was able to create an Admin account. But when I tried to login using the old account. It was not able to log me in and saying `The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later.` I'm not sure what went wrong as I didn't get any error. Is there a way to fix this?

Note: I already editted the crypt key to the migration script in opensource-opensource/1.6.0/config.xml

Answer (score 1):

```
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.3.5
```

Fixes the issue. Even if you didn't use the migration tool to migrate - version ~2.3 has an added authentication plugin which fixes the issue. Posting here, as I'm running Magento 2.3.5 but this module was still on 2.3.4.. which doesn't have the authentication plugin for bcrypt passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You can test with the following command which helps you to unblock your current admin account.

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock <username>
```

Like : `php bin/magento admin:user:unlock admin`

Reference from : [enter link description here](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/you-did-not-sign-in-correctly-or-your-account-is-temporarily-disabled-magento-2.html)

I hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

If your Magento 1 store was fully patched then accounts created/updated on or around October 2019 will need to reset their password before using the account in Magento 2.

This is due to the patch SUPEE-11219 implementing BCRYPT password hashing into the Magento 1 store, but this format is not support in Magento 2 currently. I've attached the relevent github issue below.

If you want to validate this, if you open your database and look at the `password_hash` in the `customer_entity` table. If the password hash begins with `$2y$` its using BCRYPT.

To obtain a list of affected customers you can run the following SQL query on the database.

```sql
SELECT email from customer_entity WHERE password_hash LIKE '$2y$%';
```

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26731

Comment: so you're saying that all the user in my Magento 1 account should reset their password to be able to login right?

Comment: @MadzQuestioning, it most likely wont be all customers just people who updated their password since the new hashing was introduced. I've updated my answer with a SQL query where you can find how many / emails of affected customers

Comment: I tried this but no email appeared. Does this mean that everything should be working as expected? and everyone should be able to login without a problem?

Comment: Frontend customers wont be affected by this issue then. Just to confirm are we talking about admin users or frontend customers?

Comment: both actually I want Admin users and Frontend users to retain their old password and account after the migration